# Error in building apk react-native project

Tags: android, react-native

When I want to generate apk from react-native I See this errors:

````
45 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 44 up-to-date
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: AAPT Process manager cannot be shut down while daemons are in use
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:96)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.RegisteredAaptService.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:61)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.workeractions.WorkerActionServiceRegistry$shutdownAllRegisteredServices$1$1.run(WorkerActionServiceRegistry.kt:96)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)```
````

Answer (score 1):

check if you any image or component of not supported forma. In my case it was a png image which was actually a gif.